# How to embed Instagram post without resizing the container

Tags: html, css, wordpress, instagram

I'm trying to embed Instagram photo/video post in my WordPress post. The embed works fine desktop version, but in mobile, it expands the container making everything look smaller.

[See: Screenshot of mobile version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAr6c.jpg)

To prevent this I used embed iframe code from embedresponsively.com but it leaves some white spaces at the bottom of the post.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESQkK.jpg)

How to I properly embed Instagram post for all device sizes?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this [solution](https://theme.co/forum/t/instagram-embeds-not-sizing-properly-on-mobile/60299) be useful for you:

```
iframe.instagram-media {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    min-width: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think now Instagram posts can automatically embed into a Wordpress post without creating any display problem on every device. Have you checked also this https://www.instagram.com/developer/embedding/

Also when you try to embed an Instagram Post on a WP post/page by [Embedresponsively](http://embedresponsively.com/) you can edit the styles and reduce the **padding-bottom**.

```css
.embed-container {
  position: relative; 
  padding-bottom: 120%; 
  height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden;} 

.embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; }
```

```html
<div class='embed-container'><iframe src='//instagram.com/p/dnQi4EGuZx/embed/' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowtransparency='true'></iframe></div>
```

Code given by default by Embedresponsively:

```
<style>.embed-container {position: relative; padding-bottom: 120%; height: 0; overflow: hidden;} .embed-container iframe, .embed-container object, .embed-container embed { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 95%; }</style><div class='embed-container'><iframe src='//instagram.com/p/dnQi4EGuZx/embed/' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' allowtransparency='true'></iframe></div>
```

Comment: The problem is when I embed Instagram post directly using embed option, it loads with max width, and after loading completely, it fits inside the container. But a few days back I monetized my website with google ads. When the page loads, Instagram's post is of max width, and at the same time Google ads loads as well with the available space. So it remains broke even after completely loading because ads don't resize after loaded.

Comment: Is there any picture you can show me? 
Did you try the way I told you with Embedresponsively?

Comment: I changed the container implementation from flexbox to floating divs. It works fine. I guess flexbox is not supported in many browsers yet. So I'll avoid using it for some time.